# TypeScript: Generics: Is there a safe and strict way to pick properties? (which must exist on source AND target type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to transform type A to type B, but I want to get warnings if I choose properties which are not defined on both types.

```
type Source = {
  id: number;
  foo: string;
  onlyOnSource: string;
}

type Target = {
  id: number;
  foo: string;
  onlyOnTarget?: string;
}


const source: Source = {
  id: 1,
  foo: 'hello',
  onlyOnSource: 'test',
}

const transformer1 = (response?: Source): Partial<Target> => {
  return {
    id: response?.id,
    foo: response?.foo,
    // wrong: undefined, // cool. error is catched: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'wrong' does not exist in type 'Partial<Target>'
    // onlyOnTarget: response?.onlyOnTarget, // cool. error is catched: Property 'onlyOnTarget' does not exist on type 'Source'
  };
};
```

...overall this works best. But I have to write all the properties twice (id, foo).
And it's possible to assign them wrong (i.e. `id: response?.foo`)

So I tried a generic "safePick" function (which is similar to lodash/pick, but warns when properties do not exist)

```
const safePick = <T, K extends keyof T>(source?: T, ...keys: K[]): Partial<Pick<T, K>> => {
      if (!source) return {};
      const target: Partial<Pick<T, K>> = {};
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (source[key] !== undefined) target[key] = source[key];
      });
      return target;
    };

const transformer2 = (response?: Source): Partial<Target> => {
  // return safePick(response, 'id', 'foo', 'wrong'); // cool. error is catched: Argument of type '"wrong"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Source'
  return safePick(response, 'id', 'foo', 'onlyOnSource'); // WRONG! 'onlyOnSource' should not be alowed on type Target!
};
```

But that's not complaining when I assign the property "onlyOnSource" to type Target. :(

Even when I remove the "Partial" part, it still doesn't care.

But I want this to fail with a warning. Ideally in a generic way, so I don't have to pass all the keys of both types manually.

I tried many things. Even using "zod". But couldn't find a nice solution. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why do you make the input optional `(response?: Source): Partial<Target>`?
What happen if you don't pass an input with this function?

Comment: Even without the optional and the Partial it doesn't work. (I need this because the transformer has to transform a state to a form-object. If the form is not yet filled - for example during first creation - the state is not yet there, that's why a Partial is enough at this state. The validation that everything was filled is performed later)

Comment: This is because `Partial<Pick<Source, "id" | "foo" | "onlyOnSource">>` and `Partial<Target>` are assignable to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `Target` type to the function also as argument. This is because object with extra fields will be subtype of return type of `Patrial<Target>` so it won't fail as you want.

Then use that type to compute some wrong return type if there is extra field.

```
const safePick = <Target>() => {
    return <T, K extends keyof T>(source?: T, ...keys: K[]): TargetType<Target, K, T> => {
        // @ts-ignore
      if (!source) return {};
      const target: Partial<Pick<T, K>> = {};
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (source[key] !== undefined) target[key] = source[key];
      });
        // @ts-ignore
      return target;
    };
}
```

The type-level function that will compute wrong type is this one:

```
type TargetType<Target, K extends keyof T, T> = Exclude<K, keyof Target> extends never ? Partial<Pick<T, K>> : void
```

Here, you check what is the result, if you take all keys of Source and exclude from it all keys of Target. If there is `never`, that means there is no extra fields in Source, and you can safely return your desired type. Otherwise, return "fail" type void, that will cause compilation error.

```
const transformer2 = (response?: Source): Partial<Target> => {
  return safePick<Target>()(response, 'id', 'onlyOnSource'); // WRONG! 'onlyOnSource' should not be alowed on type Target!
};
```

This will then result in this:

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Target>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: wow! this is very informative and helpful. and impressive :) thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!